# foreach get value from selected item

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach, each

How to fire foreach value from the option selected?

I have tried below but it's fired the same value on each.

```js
$(".fida").on("change", function() {
  //Getting Value
  var value = $(this).val();
  $(".abi").val(value);
  alert(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="fida">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="666">666</option>
  <option value="777">777</option>
  <option value="888">888</option>
  <option value="999">999</option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="abi" placeholder="get value from selected" />

<select class="fida">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="777">777</option>
  <option value="888">888</option>
  <option value="999">999</option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="abi" placeholder="get value from selected" />
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/abilashu/8mazw2cg/62/

Comment: You are writing the value of one select into both instances of `.abi`. Your username is not very appropriate.

Comment: Are these form controls wrapped in parent containers? If so show the higher level structure for them. You can use indexing to target the applicable input but using their parent wrappers is often the easiest and most common way

Comment: Those are used in foreach loop

Answer (score 1):

`$(".abi")` returns all instances of that selector. So by using `$(".abi").val(value)` you assign the `value` of both `input` elements.

In your case you should use [next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to only set the value on the `input` next to `select` and not both instances of `.abi`.

Be aware that this way has limitations and depends on your DOM structure, which I would not recommend. Like *charlietfl* wrote it is usually better to use an identifier or a wrapper.

```js
$(".fida").on("change", function() {
  //Getting Value
  var value = $(this).val();
  $(this).next().val(value);
  alert(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="fida">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="666">666</option>
  <option value="777">777</option>
  <option value="888">888</option>
  <option value="999">999</option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="abi" placeholder="get value from selected" />

<select class="fida">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="777">777</option>
  <option value="888">888</option>
  <option value="999">999</option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="abi" placeholder="get value from selected" />
```

### Edit:

If you change your DOM it gets more reliable. For example by using wrappers:

```js
$(".fida").on("change", function() {
  //Getting Value
  var value = $(this).val();
  $(this).parent().find(".abi").val(value);
  alert(value);
});
```

```css
div{display: inline-block}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select class="fida">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="666">666</option>
    <option value="777">777</option>
    <option value="888">888</option>
    <option value="999">999</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" class="abi" placeholder="get value from selected" />
</div>

<div>
  <select class="fida">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="777">777</option>
    <option value="888">888</option>
    <option value="999">999</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" class="abi" placeholder="get value from selected" />
</div>
```

Comment: using .next() just working here, but not working everywhere.

Comment: Another way to answer it?

Comment: Not with the code you provided. As was also explained in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

One technique you can use which is bound to work all the time is the positioning of the elements, **provided that the first `select` element corresponds to the first `input` element, and the second to the second, etc**:

```
//Get index of select
let index = $(this).index('.fida');
//Only set value of corresponding input element
$(".abi").eq(index).val(value);
```

```js
$(".fida").on("change", function() {
  //Getting Value
  var value = $(this).val();
  //Get index of select
  let index = $(this).index('.fida');
  //Only set value on corresponding input element
  $(".abi").eq(index).val(value);
  console.log(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="fida">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="666">666</option>
  <option value="777">777</option>
  <option value="888">888</option>
  <option value="999">999</option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="abi" placeholder="get value from selected" />

<select class="fida">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="777">777</option>
  <option value="888">888</option>
  <option value="999">999</option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="abi" placeholder="get value from selected" />
```